# Html <a> tag downloading instead of opening

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I made this *navbar* for my website

```html
<div class = "navbar">
            <a href= "index.html">HOME</a>
            <a href= "apps.html">APPS</a>
            <a href= "contact.html">CONTACT</a>
            <a href= "about.html">ABOUT</a>
</div>
```

But when I click on HOME, APPS, CONTACT, or ABOUT, it downloads the corresponding file instead of opening it! Why and how do I fix it?

I am not sure if there's a thing like this but for some reason, I tried doing this:

```html
<a href="xyz" download="false"> </a>
```

It didn't work obviously.

Comment: Where is the site hosted?

Comment: `download` is a boolean attribute. it has no value, it is true by its pure existing. That means, that `download="false"` is still true as the value is ignored and the existence of the attribute makes it true.

Comment: Hi & Welcome! This seems a very "environment specific" problem (Server(/env/deployment/Network/Routing/Access/url(!)..rewriting, Rules), Client??) ..for the "solution", you have to "reproduce" the ("relevant") "details")

Comment: This would first of all suggest, that likely the web server you have this on, does not deliver `.html` files with the correct `Content-Type` header. But if you have this navbar element in a file that is also named with the `.html` suffix, then you should have had that same problem already, when you tried to load _that_ document ... If that is the case, but did not have that same problem - then perhaps the resulting URLs are simply wrong, and your server gives a 404 response (and _that_ one then doesn't come with a correct Content-Type.)

Comment: Open your browser dev tools, network panel, and check the response headers for the relevant request. (Activate the "preserve log" option, so that it doesn't clear the content between requests.)